# Deleting event eloquent - Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

When I try to delete an **Item**, before the delete operation, my programme execute the code inside *static::deleting* event in Item class.

But when i try to deleting a **Category** my programme execute only the code inside *static::deleting* in Category Class. Why? I want execute the *static::deleting* in Item Class too.

```
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'category_id');
    }

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($category) {
            $category->items()->delete();
        });
    }
}

class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    function categorys() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Category::class, 'category_id');
    }

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($item) {
            // something
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @thursday_dan's answer states, mass update/delete queries don't trigger Eloquent events. If you still want to trigger them, you can fetch the items and delete them one by one.

```php
class Category extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    function items() {
        return $this->hasMany(Item::class, 'category_id');
    }

    protected static function booted()
    {
        static::deleting(function ($category) {
            $category->items()->get()->each->delete();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, it appears you cannot trigger the item delete event via the category delete event.

From the docs on laravel you can see this message regarding events and mass-deletes/eloquent deletes:

> When issuing a mass update or delete query via Eloquent, the saved, updated, deleting, and deleted model events will not be dispatched for the affected models. This is because the models are never actually retrieved when performing mass updates or deletes.

[Here is a link to the relevant portion.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#events)